# Using getBackgroundPage() gives me: Object [object Window] has no method 'getFromStorage'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this in my background.js:

```
var write = function (line) {
  if (localStorage["silent"] == true) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(line);
  } else {
    alert(line);
  }
}
var getFromStorage = function (item, default) {
  if (localStorage[item] == undefined) {
    write("Could not find " + item + " in local storage...");
    return default;
  } else {
    return localStorage[item];
  }
}

var isOn = getFromStorage("isOn", true);
var silent = getFromStorage("silent", false);
```

And this in my popup.js:

```
var bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var isOn = bgPage.getFromStorage("isOn", true);
var silent = bgPage.getFromStorage("silent", false);
```

And I get this error:

```
Object [object Window] has no method 'getFromStorage'
```

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Is the `getFromStorage` variable defined at global level? Try `window.getFromStorage = ...` instead. (Also, why are you using `getBackgroundPage()` in the background page itself?)

Comment: The first thing to notice is that `default` is reserved, you shouldn't/can't use it as parameter

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, getFromStorage is global as long as it's in the background page, I think, so I'll just try your suggestion. And apparently I can't use console.log without using getBackgroundPage in the background page, which I know doesn't make sense, but what can I do?
EDIT: apparently stuff in the background page aren't global, so I can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the  `default` parameter in your background script

```
  var write = function (line) {
    if (localStorage["silent"] == true) {
      chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(line);
    } else {
      alert(line);
    }
  }
  var getFromStorage = function (item, d) {
    if (localStorage[item] == undefined) {
      write("Could not find " + item + " in local storage...");
      return d;
    } else {
      return localStorage[item];
    }
  }

  var isOn = getFromStorage("isOn", true);
  var silent = getFromStorage("silent", false);
```

Because `default` is reserved in javascript. (It is used in conjunction with the [Switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp))
Therefore the background page wouldn't load at all and Inspecting it should result in something like this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token default  at background.js:8`

Which then leads to the error `Object [object Window] has no method 'getFromStorage'`
in your popup script, because `getFromStorage` actually never has been loaded in your background script because of terminating at Line 8

Comment: Oh wow, okay...thanks a lot, I'm still a javascript no0b so :P